# python grpc DNS resolution failed

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I have been attempting to connect to a gRPC server hosted behind the domain name "example.com/server".

I am using grpc.secure_channel to establish the connection. However, I encounter the error message `DNS resolution failed for example.com/server: UNKNOWN: Name or service not known`. Interestingly, if I change the domain name to just "example.com", the connection works fine. It seems that the `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER` is unable to resolve domain names that include a directory path after the hostname.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

```
channel_credential = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(crt.encode())
channel = grpc.secure_channel('example.com/server', channel_credential)
intercept_channel = grpc.intercept_channel(channel)
stub = project_pb2_grpc.MyStub(intercept_channel)
stub.task()
```

Comment: This behavior appears to be correct. DNS names may contain only alphabetic characters (`A-Z`), numeric characters (`0-9`), the minus sign (`-`), and the period (`.`).  gRPC clients connect to gRPC servers through a combination of DNS name (e.g. `example.com`), port (e.g. `50051`), optional package, mandatory `Service` and `Method` names.

Comment: In your case, you will need to know which port the gRPC server is listening on (define the variable  `port`) and then you can use e.g.`grpc.secure_channel(f"example.com:{port}", channel_credential)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC does not use paths, you should only provide the server name.